# set the document root

Tags: .htaccess

I have a dedicated server **Centos 6** that I use to store files only. My files are not in a folder `/home/public_html/`, are located in a folder in the server root `/srv/files/`.

How can I activate. `Htaccess` in this directory `/srv/files/`?

I am setting up the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` as follows:

```
<Directory '/srv/arqivos/'>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Restart apache but do not get any results.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `AllowOverride` to `All`:

```
AllowOverride All
```

I use this config for all my servers.

Comment: Try to set `AccessFileName .htaccess`, just for being sure.

Comment: # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

Comment: Please don't write mult line comments. They are not readable.

Comment: 'm sorry aquo new site, I do not know how to set up, but I'll improve

Comment: Please edit your question and add how you set the document root.

Comment: I can only restart Apache or need to restart the server?

Comment: you just need to restart the apache. (`/etc/init.d/apache restart`)

Comment: without result, I am using function

Comment: By the way a referer is optional.